# Project 3D Vector into object orientation

Tags: 3d, physics, vector-space

So I'm currently attempting to project a 3D Vector (obtained from an accelerometer) into the object orientation (obtained by integrating the angular velocity obtained from the object gyroscope, returned as a 3D Vector). However I'm not really sure how to do that.

I'm using an Excel spreadsheet right now to know which results I can expect from the test data to be imported into the software I'm working on.

Comment: You mean a dot product ?

Comment: How do you represent the orientation? (It would help if you gave these things names.)

Answer (score 0):

Projecting a vector **v** onto another vector **p** is as simple as computing the dot product of the former with a unit length vector in the direction of the latter **n<sub>p</sub>**:

**v<sub>p</sub>** = (**v**.**n<sub>p</sub>**)**n<sub>p</sub>** = (**v**.**p** / ||**p**||<sup>2</sup>)**p**

Component-wise that is:

```
// Dot product of v and p
vdp = v.x*p.x + v.y*p.y + v.z*p.z
// Square norm of p
p2 = p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y + p.z*p.z
// Projection
vp.x = (vdp / p2) * p.x
vp.y = (vdp / p2) * p.y
vp.z = (vdp / p2) * p.z
```

The length of the projection itself is **v**.**n<sub>p</sub>**, which is equal to `vdp / sqrt(p2)`.